# How do I create surveys in Sitecore?

Tags: .net, content-management-system, sitecore, survey

We need to show the user a set of questions, one after the other. Based on the results, the user will be shown a set of products.

Could this be done with Sitecore (apart from using custom layouts)?

Comment: Is this set of questions going to be changed?

Comment: Yes. An admin will be able to change the questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, Sitecore does not have this functionality.
It is basically a framework for website development and does not contain a lot of modules by default, but you can create a survey application by programming it.

If you have a license for the DMS module (digital marketing system) in combination with the Web Forms for Marketeers module, then you can create a survey with those.
Web Forms can be used to create the survey forms and DMS can be used to track the results.

Answer (score 5):

You might find the [Poll shared source module](http://trac.sitecore.net/Poll) useful. It has been upgraded to the latest major version of Sitecore and seems to integrate with DMS as well. Besides, [it was tested and is supported by Sitecore](http://trac.sitecore.net/Index/wiki/Better).

Answer (score 1):

I have successfully implemented surveys using [Web Forms for Marketers](http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sdn5/products/web_forms2/web_forms_for_marketers_v2_reference_usletter.pdf) (WFFM) in a production environment. By default, the data is collected in a local SQLite database, however, Sitecore provides a SQL database and data-provider which is handy if your production environment has multiple CD instances.

The forms can be attached to any placeholder you designate, just as you do with Renderings and Sublayouts.

Regarding your conditional logic... like all things Sitecore, WFFM offers several places you can "hook" into. Below is an example of a custom "Submit" action. You can combine your custom actions with any of the "out of box" actions that Sitecore provides.

```
class RedirectToRegistrationForm : BaseSaveAction
{
    public override void Execute(ID formid, AdaptedResultList fields, params object[] data)
    {
        AdaptedControlResult result = fields.GetEntryByName("Entry Name");
        switch(result.Value)
        {
            case "Condition 1":
                // do something...
                break;

            case "Condition 2":
                // do something else...
                break;
        }
    }
}
```